# Module Installation errors when trying to use local::lib and CPAN

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan, locallib

I am trying to use `local::lib` as I don’t have admin rights on the system and I want to download and install a local library. I ran following:

```
perl Makefile.PL --bootstrap

make test && make install

echo 'eval $(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)' >>~/.bashrc
```

After this I tried to download the Module via cpan
by running `perl -MCPAN -e shell install netAddr::IP` but when i am running my program it's giving an error:

```
Can't locate NetAddr/IP.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at agha.pl line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at agha.pl line 8.
```

I took that to mean the module is not installed... So I again tried to go through CPAN, but now *it's* giving an error (this is in Linux):

```
-bash-3.2$ perl -MCPAN -e shell

There seems to be running another CPAN process (pid 15611).  Contacting...
Other job is running.
You may want to kill it and delete the lockfile, maybe. On UNIX try:
kill 15611
rm /homes/ar312/.cpan/.lock
```

Comment: It doesn't mean that the module is not installed. It just means that your script cannot find it. How are you running your script. Did you modify the script so it uses loacal::lib?

Comment: what change i should do. i am currently using

Comment: #!/usr/local/bin/perl

Comment: how can i do that plz.

Comment: Can you plz answer my questions? And maybe fix your shift key?

Comment: i have not made any change in my script what changes i have to make .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [local::lib documentation](http://p3rl.org/local%3a%3alib):

> After writing your shell configuration file, be sure to re-read it to get the changed settings into your current shell's environment.

You forgot to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In all seriousness, save yourself a ton of time and trouble by installing [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/).

> perlbrew is a tool to manage multiple perl installations in your $HOME directory. They are completely isolated perl universes. This approach has many benefits:

- No need to run sudo to install CPAN modules, any more.
- Try the monthly released new perls.
- Learn new language features.
- Test your production code against different perl versions.
- Leave vendor perl (the one that comes with OS) alone

Comment: Even though it doesn't directly answer the OP's question, this is an option definitely worth giving consideration.